# Braces AROUND the WHOLE try/catch statement in java are needed? Really weird stuff

Tags: java, android, try-catch, curly-braces

I need to resolve the package version from manifest in Android. I do it straight in the main activity, don't know if it's wrong.

I can't test if this works now, for various reasons I wouldn't be able in a few days despite I'm running Eclipse but this really hurts my mind as I'm a rather worrying person:

```
{ try {
    String version = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
} }
```

Do you notice the braces before and after the WHOLE statement? If I delete them, Eclipse will say

"Syntax error on token "{", { expected after this token"

in the preceding activity opening, and similar stuff in any method or statement after it.

I googled for it because it's what I can do, and found nothing about them being needed. Java tutorials, samples spell try catch without this. Am I doing something very stupid or is it normal behaviour and my code *should* run when I'm back?

Again sorry for this question but I just needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post more of the surrounding code for us to look at? Where is this try/catch block located?

Comment: Can you add more context?  What comes before the try?  If this is the body of a function then you certainly need the braces, but if this is just part of the body of a function then that's weird.

Comment: Where is the code located... Maybe you are not inside a method?

Comment: Post the code that comes **before** the `try` statement

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
 try {
     String version = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
 } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
     Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
 }

// continuation of the mainactivity}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have that code outside any method. With the braces, Java treats it as an instance initializer block. Without the braces, it's illegal.

Another thing wrong with that code is that you initialize the variable `version` and then immediately lose the information because `version` is local to the `try` block. The variable should probably be declared outside the block.

Comment: so, I need to create a method? Woah, I need to learn more, at the time when I can't compile anything .

Comment: about the version string, ok. I should add public String version;

Comment: If this is in an Activity, you'll have to have an `onCreate` method regardless. Just declare `version` to be a field of your activity subclass and move the `try/catch` block into `onCreate`.

Comment: and I already need to declare the string outside onCreate as public static 'cause it needs to be invoked in a separate class. thanks, however!

Comment: @emha - I don't think you can initialize this as a static (at least not with a static initializer). The method `getPackageManager()` is an instance method of Activity (inherited, actually, from ContextWrapper). You can only initialize `version` once you have a context that has been properly initialized by the system.

Comment: I was referring to declare it as public static String version; in the main activity and then use this variable in onCreate to get package version, and pass it to another class by MainActivity.version. (I didn't check if I can do the getting work from additional classes.) The value will be lost, or we misunderstood ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this try block is right inside `class {` in your code.

If so, you need them because in java it is treated as [instance initialize](http://www.javatpoint.com/instance-initializer-block) block.

```
EDIT:
```

After more information added to question, yes, this shouldn't be initializater block, it should be wrapped inside a method.

Comment: Q: Does Java require braces AROUND the WHOLE try/catch statement?  A: No, of course not ;).  The OP is doing something weird.  "A try block right inside a class" is a good guess, but I don't like to guess. The OP needs to show us what comes *before* is "try/catch".  IMHO...